# How to read a csv, which changes structure, into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

The csv I'm trying to import via read_csv is giving me trouble since some row are missing values in the, which causes trailing commas, thus messing up how it is being read into my dataframe.

Data from [Kaggle: Facebook Ad Campaign](https://www.kaggle.com/madislemsalu/facebook-ad-campaign)

#### CSV Example Rows

```
1121593,26/08/2017,26/08/2017,1178,144622,45-49,M,10,16,16,1177535,221,365.6600009,15,3
1121594,26/08/2017,26/08/2017,45-49,M,10,14,14,426500,72,128.2799988,4,1,,
```

```py
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None)

# result
        0           1           2      3       4      5   6   7       8   9            10   11           12  13 14
0  1121593  26/08/2017  26/08/2017   1178  144622  45-49   M  10      16  16      1177535  221  365.6600009  15  3
1  1121594  26/08/2017  26/08/2017  45-49       M     10  14  14  426500  72  128.2799988    4            1
```

#### Desired

```py
        0           1           2       3         4      5  6   7   8   9        10   11          12  13  14
0  1121593  26/08/2017  26/08/2017  1178.0  144622.0  45-49  M  10  16  16  1177535  221  365.660001  15   3
1  1121594  26/08/2017  26/08/2017     NaN       NaN  45-49  M  10  14  14   426500   72  128.279999   4   1
```

Any suggestions on how to handle this data? Ideally, the missing values (before 45-49 in the second row) would just show up as NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get bad datasets that have a known fault, a good solution is to scrub the data and write the good stuff back to disk. That code only needs to run after a download and your other code isn't burdened with cruft from the fix. This is best done using the csv module where we can just fix line by line.

kaggle_campaign_data_fixer.py

```
import sys
import csv
from pathlib import Path

filename = Path(sys.argv[1])
newname = filename.parent/f"{filename.stem}-fixed{filename.suffix}"

BADCOLS = ['', '']

with open(filename, newline='') as infile, open(newname, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in csv.reader(infile):
        if row[-2:] == BADCOLS:
            row[3:3] = BADCOLS
            del row[-2:]
        writer.writerow(row)

# test it
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)
print(df)
print("""
============== FIXED ==================
""")
df = pd.read_csv(newname, header=None)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

- The issue is the dataset
- Beginning at row 762 (0 indexed), the data no longer contains `'campaign_id'` and `'fb_campaign_id'`
- I suggest reading the data into two separate dataframes
- Add the missing columns with `None` values to `df2`
- Sort the `df2` columns to match the order of `df1`
- Combine the two dataframes.
- The dataset from [Facebook Ad Campaign](https://www.kaggle.com/madislemsalu/facebook-ad-campaign), which has issues, seems to be a copy of [Sales Conversion Optimization](https://www.kaggle.com/loveall/clicks-conversion-tracking), which does not have this issue.

  - As noted in this dataset [discussion](https://www.kaggle.com/madislemsalu/facebook-ad-campaign/discussion/149325).
  - So it may be easiest to use the dataset without the added issues.

```py
import pandas as pd

# read through row 761
df1 = pd.read_csv('data.csv', skiprows=range(762, 1145))

# create a different header for the 2nd part of the data
cols = df1.columns[:3].tolist() + df1.columns[5:].tolist()

# read from row 762 and skip the two blank end columns
df2 = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, names=cols, skiprows=range(762), usecols=range(13))

# add the missing columns to df2
df2[['campaign_id', 'fb_campaign_id']] = None

# sort df2 columns by the same order as df1
df2 = df2.reindex(df1.columns, axis=1)

# combine the two dataframes
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

### `df` - head and tail

```
  ad_id reporting_start reporting_end campaign_id fb_campaign_id    age gender  interest1  interest2  interest3  impressions  clicks  spent  total_conversion  approved_conversion
 708746      17/08/2017    17/08/2017         916         103916  30-34      M         15         17         17         7350       1   1.43                 2                    1
 708749      17/08/2017    17/08/2017         916         103917  30-34      M         16         19         21        17861       2   1.82                 2                    0
 708771      17/08/2017    17/08/2017         916         103920  30-34      M         20         25         22          693       0   0.00                 1                    0
 708815      30/08/2017    30/08/2017         916         103928  30-34      M         28         32         32         4259       1   1.25                 1                    0
 708818      17/08/2017    17/08/2017         916         103928  30-34      M         28         33         32         4133       1   1.29                 1                    1
 1314410      19/08/2017    19/08/2017        None           None  45-49      F        109        111        114      1129773     252  358.189997                13                    2
 1314411      19/08/2017    19/08/2017        None           None  45-49      F        110        111        116       637549     120  173.880003                 3                    0
 1314412      19/08/2017    19/08/2017        None           None  45-49      F        111        113        117       151531      28   40.289999                 2                    0
 1314414      17/08/2017    17/08/2017        None           None  45-49      F        113        114        117       790253     135  198.710000                 8                    2
 1314415      17/08/2017    17/08/2017        None           None  45-49      F        114        116        118       513161     114  165.609999                 5                    2
```

### `df1` - head and tail

```
  ad_id reporting_start reporting_end  campaign_id  fb_campaign_id    age gender  interest1  interest2  interest3  impressions  clicks  spent  total_conversion  approved_conversion
 708746      17/08/2017    17/08/2017          916          103916  30-34      M         15         17         17         7350       1   1.43                 2                    1
 708749      17/08/2017    17/08/2017          916          103917  30-34      M         16         19         21        17861       2   1.82                 2                    0
 708771      17/08/2017    17/08/2017          916          103920  30-34      M         20         25         22          693       0   0.00                 1                    0
 708815      30/08/2017    30/08/2017          916          103928  30-34      M         28         32         32         4259       1   1.25                 1                    0
 708818      17/08/2017    17/08/2017          916          103928  30-34      M         28         33         32         4133       1   1.29                 1                    1
 1121585      20/08/2017    20/08/2017         1178          144621  40-44      M         66         72         68         9773       1    1.460000                 1                    0
 1121589      20/08/2017    20/08/2017         1178          144622  45-49      M         10         16         11       464036      77  123.550000                 3                    1
 1121590      20/08/2017    20/08/2017         1178          144622  45-49      M         10         16         15       478480      75  135.750001                 3                    1
 1121592      20/08/2017    20/08/2017         1178          144622  45-49      M         10         14         11       428812      66  116.880000                 4                    2
 1121593      26/08/2017    26/08/2017         1178          144622  45-49      M         10         16         16      1177535     221  365.660001                15                    3
```

### `df2` - head and tail

```
   ad_id reporting_start reporting_end    age gender  interest1  interest2  interest3  impressions  clicks       spent  total_conversion  approved_conversion
 1121594      26/08/2017    26/08/2017  45-49      M         10         14         14       426500      72  128.279999                 4                    1
 1121597      30/08/2017    30/08/2017  45-49      M         15         21         19        54237       7   10.780000                 2                    1
 1121598      30/08/2017    30/08/2017  45-49      M         15         19         18       506916      89  133.699999                 2                    2
 1121599      30/08/2017    30/08/2017  45-49      M         15         17         18       250960      42   64.880000                 2                    0
 1121601      30/08/2017    30/08/2017  45-49      M         16         20         18      2286228     353  603.380002                16                    7
 1314410      19/08/2017    19/08/2017  45-49      F        109        111        114      1129773     252  358.189997                13                    2
 1314411      19/08/2017    19/08/2017  45-49      F        110        111        116       637549     120  173.880003                 3                    0
 1314412      19/08/2017    19/08/2017  45-49      F        111        113        117       151531      28   40.289999                 2                    0
 1314414      17/08/2017    17/08/2017  45-49      F        113        114        117       790253     135  198.710000                 8                    2
 1314415      17/08/2017    17/08/2017  45-49      F        114        116        118       513161     114  165.609999                 5                    2
```